# ReactJS NPM module: Undefined error

Tags: reactjs

I copied a ReactJS project to a new folder, made some changes, and it's not finding the react NPM module. I stripped the app down to 1 simple file, took out all the major code. This is driving me nuts, I deleted the `node_modules` folder, and ran `NPM install`.

I'm using `watchify`:
watchify --debug -t reactify app3.jsx -o ./build/app-brow.js

I Restarted my Terminal console in case that was out of sync, still can't find react.

I copied the original project to another folder, and it works OK from that copy, there's something about the code/files below that I'm missing.

It shows `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`, here which is the JS return code in my `render`:

```
     React.createElement("div", null, 
        "Test, TEST TEST."
     )
```

FILES:
app.jsx

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */


var React = require('react');

var App = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
      return (
         <div>
            Test, TEST TEST.
         </div>
      );
  } 
}); 


React.renderComponent((
   <App />
), document.body);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test 3</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    HAH... If you see this there is an error, make sure JavaScript is enabled in your browser.

    <script type="text/javascript" src="build/app-brow.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Test3",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "0.11.x",
    "reactify": "0.14.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reactify is compiling your JSX in the React 0.12 style, but you are using React 0.11. Either upgrade React to 0.12.x or downgrade Reactify to a version that uses react-tools 0.11.